# Evaluate $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt{n}x_n$ with $x_{n+1}=x_{n} (1-x_{n}^2)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, recurrence-relations

Question: Let $(x_n)_{n\geq1}$ be a sequence such that $x_1 \in (0,1)$ and $$x_{n+1}=x_{n} (1-x_{n}^2)\tag{1}$$ for $n \geq 1$. 
Evaluate $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt{n}x_n$.

**The Hint Given: Fine upper and lower bound**

My attempt: Working backwards, the sequence is stationary at $x_n = 1/\sqrt{2}$, so I suspect that to be the limit as well. But I'm not able to find any upper or lower bound. 
I'm thinking of an upper bound $$x_n < \frac{1}{\sqrt{2n+2}},\tag{2}$$ but I'm struggling to show this by induction.
Any hints is appreciated

Comment: if $x_1 \leq 0.8$ then the limit is $0$.

Comment: the sequence is **always** decreasing because multiplying two numbers between $0$ and $1$ will result a number smaller than both.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the recurrence, we get $$x^2_{n+1}=x^2_n\,(1-x^2_n)^2$$ and thus $$x^{-2}_{n+1}=x^{-2}_n+\frac1{1-x^2_n}+\frac1{(1-x^2_n)^2}\ge x^{-2}_n+2,$$ so
$$x^{-2}_n\ge x^{-2}_1+2n-1>2n.$$ So $$\lim_{n\to\infty}x^2_n=0,$$ and by the [Stolz–Cesàro theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem), $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x^{-2}_n}n=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x^{-2}_{n+1}-x^{-2}_n}{(n+1)-n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac1{1-x^2_n}+\frac1{(1-x^2_n)^2}\right)=2.$$ Thus $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt{n}x_n=\sqrt{1/2}$.